Couriers Delivered On Same Date using RDBMS
Write a query to display the courier details such as courier id with the alias name 'COURIER1' and the courier id of the courier that got delivered on the same date as courier1 with the alias name 'COURIER2' and the delivered date.
Sort the records by the delivery date in descending order and then by the courier id of courier1 in descending order.
Display the output in RDBMS.

SELECT 
    c1.courier_id AS COURIER1,
    c2.courier_id AS COURIER2,
    c2.delivered_date
FROM 
    couriers c1
JOIN 
    couriers c2 ON c1.delivered_date = c2.delivered_date AND c1.courier_id <> c2.courier_id
WHERE 
    c1.courier_id = 'your_courier_id'
ORDER BY 
    c2.delivered_date DESC, c1.courier_id DESC;


Here is the solution:
SELECT 
    c1.courier_id AS COURIER1,
    c2.courier_id AS COURIER2,
    c2.delivered_date
FROM 
    courier_details c1
JOIN 
    courier_details c2 ON c1.delivered_date = c2.delivered_date
WHERE 
    c1.courier_id = 'COURIER1'
    AND c2.courier_id != 'COURIER1'
ORDER BY 
    c2.delivered_date DESC,
    c1.courier_id DESC;

